# CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds. Error=-25300 api.stripe.com iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

When I attempt to setup Customer's default payment source I am met with the following error in the console.

```
2021-05-26 01:12:54.957645-0400 appName[2274:787320] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
class = inet;
"m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
ptcl = htps;
"r_Attributes" = 1;
sdmn = Stripe;
srvr = "api.stripe.com";
sync = syna;
}
Setup failed status?
```

Bellow is a relevant function. it gets called when a `payButton` is pressed after filling out the relevant card details.

```
 @objc func pay() {
    
    print("pay func began executing")
    
    // Collect card details
    let cardParams = cardTextField.cardParams
    // Fill in any billing details...
    let billingDetails = STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails()

    // Create SetupIntent confirm parameters with the above
    let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(card: cardParams, billingDetails: billingDetails, metadata: nil)
    let setupIntentParams = STPSetupIntentConfirmParams(clientSecret: setupIntentClientSecret!)
    setupIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams

    // ...continued in next step
    // Complete the setup
    let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
    
    print(paymentMethodParams, "paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler?", setupIntentClientSecret, "hcaca face", setupIntentParams)

    paymentHandler.confirmSetupIntent(setupIntentParams, with: self) { status, setupIntent, error in
        switch (status) {
        case .failed:
            // Setup failed
            print("Setup failed status?")
            
            break
        case .canceled:
            // Setup canceled
            print("Setup canceled status?")
            
            break
        case .succeeded:
            // Setup succeeded
            print("setup sucess!")
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
            break
        }
    }

}
```

I wonder if it could in some way be related to Firebase and how it interacts with Stripe?? Let me know if you need some other parts.

Comment: We need more info based on your troubleshooting. Did you add a breakpoint in the pay button, click it, and step through the code line by line until the error is thrown? Which line was that? Were the variables correctly populated leading up to that error? For example, force-unwrapping optionals is dangerous; like here `setupIntentClientSecret!` is that nil? It should be safely unwrapped before using it as it could be nil, and if it is, you're app will randomly crash.

Comment: @Jay yes i did troubleshooting, it happens after this line is called: paymentHandler.confirmSetupIntent(setupIntentParams , and yes all the variables are correctly populated.

Comment: And you're not handling errors after that call so I would advise adding that. There is some ambiguity between your code and the code specified in the examples. How about referring to the [guide](https://github.com/stripe-archive/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/client/ios/App%20(Swift)/CheckoutViewController.swift#L112) and seeing if that code works better?